# SELECT Queries with Union and order into a new temp table is not working

Tags: sql-server, union, temp

I have writing a T-SQL query to collect some data from many tables and splitting the rows into three with select union queries. There are errors while executing the queries. I have attached the queries, please guide me to rectify the errors.

```
SELECT * 
INTO #tmpFerdeen 
FROM 
    (SELECT
         (CASE WHEN sc <> '0000' THEN sln END) AS t, 
         (CASE WHEN sc <> '0000' THEN crid END) AS crrid, 
         CASE Header 
            WHEN 'H' THEN 1  
            WHEN 'S' THEN 2 
            WHEN 'T' THEN 3 
            ELSE 0 
         END O,
         CASE 
            WHEN sc <> '0000' THEN Header 
         END, 
         CASE 
            WHEN sc <> '0000' THEN Header+'|'+st + '|'+convert(varchar,pid) + '|' + convert(varchar, cid) + '|' +convert(varchar,cenddate ) 
         END AS RestOfData
     FROM
         #tempsddd

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
         sln t, crid crrid, 
         CASE Details 
            WHEN 'H' THEN 1  
            WHEN 'S' THEN 2 
            WHEN 'T' THEN 3 
            ELSE 0 
         END,
         Details, 
         Details + '|' + ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, sln), '') + '|' + '|' + '|' + '|'
                 + ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, ah), '') + '|'
                 + ISNULL(sfne, '') + '|' 
                 + ISNULL(smne, '') + '|' 
                 + ISNULL(slne, '')
   FROM
       #tempsddd

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        (CASE WHEN sc <> '0000' THEN sln END) AS t, 
        (CASE WHEN sc <> '0000' THEN crid END) AS crrid, 
        CASE Footer 
           WHEN 'H' THEN 1  
           WHEN 'S' THEN 2 
           WHEN 'T' THEN 3 
           ELSE 0 
        END, 
        CASE WHEN sc <> '0000' THEN Footer END, 
        CASE WHEN sc <> '0000' THEN Footer + '|' + sc END
    FROM
        #tempsddd
    ORDER BY
        crrid, 
         CASE Header 
            WHEN 'H' THEN 1  
            WHEN 'S' THEN 2 
            WHEN 'T' THEN 3 
            ELSE 0 
         END)
```

Please guide me to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is icorrect syntax because of "Order by" Statement, You should put order by Out of bracket , and you also use case after order by So Please check is that case Statment is correct

Comment: Thanks dude. You made my day. Thanks now its working